# NHibernate Lambda Extensions can't use any alias query on DetachedCriteria

Tags: c#, nhibernate, detachedcriteria, nhlambdaextensions

I'm trying to write a simple query that requires an alias as it's a Many-To-Many assocation however I can't get it to work with NH Lambda Extensions. It always gives me a compile error even though as far as I can tell it's exactly the same as the documentation and all the examples I've seen online.

**Works**

```
var query = DetachedCriteria.For<County>()            
    .CreateCriteria("Zips", "zipAlias", JoinType.LeftOuterJoin)
    //.CreateCriteria<County>(x => x.Zips, 
    //                              () => zipAlias, JoinType.LeftOuterJoin)
    .Add<Zip>(zip => zip.ZipCode == zipCode);
```

**Doesn't work**

```
var query = DetachedCriteria.For<County>()            
    //.CreateCriteria("Zips", "zipAlias", JoinType.LeftOuterJoin)
    .CreateCriteria<County>(x => x.Zips, 
                                    () => zipAlias, JoinType.LeftOuterJoin)
    .Add<Zip>(zip => zip.ZipCode == zipCode);
```

Results in a build `Error   22  The name 'zipAlias' does not exist in the current context`

Intellisense also highlights the CreateCriteria**`<County>`** saying it doesn't understand the method however it does correctly show me the parameter names when I'm inside the parens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [documentation](http://nhlambdaextensions.googlecode.com/files/NhLambdaExtensions.html) is full of handy examples.

Your `zipAlias` needs to be a variable in the local scope.

```
Zip zipAlias = null;
string zipCode = "";

var query = DetachedCriteria.For<County>()
    .CreateCriteria<County>(x => x.Zips, () => zipAlias, JoinType.LeftOuterJoin)
    .Add<Zip>(zip => zip.ZipCode == zipCode);
```

As the documentation link downloads instead of rendering, I have copied some sections.

**Create Criteria Association With Alias**
Using original ICriteria API:

```
ICriteria before = CreateSession()
    .CreateCriteria(typeof(Person))
        .CreateCriteria("Children", "childAlias")
            .Add(Restrictions.Eq("Nickname", "test"));
```

Using NHibernate Lambda Extensions:

```
Child childAlias = null;
ICriteria after = CreateSession()
    .CreateCriteria(typeof(Person))
        .CreateCriteria((Person p) => p.Children, () => childAlias)
            .Add<Child>(c => c.Nickname == "test");
```

**Create Criteria Alias Association With Alias And Join Type**
Using original ICriteria API:

```
ICriteria before = CreateSession()
    .CreateCriteria(typeof(Person), "personAlias")
        .CreateCriteria("personAlias.Children", "childAlias", JoinType.LeftOuterJoin)
            .Add(Restrictions.Eq("Nickname", "test"));
```

Using NHibernate Lambda Extensions:

```
Person personAlias = null;
Child childAlias = null;
ICriteria after = CreateSession()
    .CreateCriteria(typeof(Person), () => personAlias)
        .CreateCriteria(() => personAlias.Children, () => childAlias, JoinType.LeftOuterJoin)
            .Add<Child>(c => c.Nickname == "test");
```

**Create Criteria Association With Alias And Join Type**
Using original ICriteria API:

```
DetachedCriteria before =
    DetachedCriteria.For<Person>()
        .CreateCriteria("Children", "childAlias", JoinType.LeftOuterJoin)
            .Add(Restrictions.Eq("Nickname", "test"));
```

Using NHibernate Lambda Extensions:

```
Child childAlias = null;
DetachedCriteria after =
    DetachedCriteria.For<Person>()
        .CreateCriteria((Person p) => p.Children, () => childAlias, JoinType.LeftOuterJoin)
            .Add<Child>(c => c.Nickname == "test");
```

Comment: well that was very unintuitive I didn't even see there were variable declarations in there as I was looking at what occurred after the `.For<>`

Comment: In which namespace does the Child data type reside?  I can't seem to find it.